# Touch drawing not working when UIPanGestureRecognizer implemented for view

Tags: ios, swift, view, uipangesturerecognizer

I have screen to test the device touch screen with popping bubbles. And some imageView added in subviews of bubbles made of cross for them. Then user swipe over the bubbles to check the touch screen.

And I want drawing on the same view. When user swipes the finger over the bubbles, a line will be drawn. I have separate class for drawing and assign it to main parent view of controller.

If I remove code for UIPanGestureRecognizer then drawing works and there are no lags.
If I add gesture to view for popping the bubbles like this

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Then there is a lag, and drawing doesn't work.

I want both things like popping bubbles and drawing on view.
The main problem of this gesture is when I add this in view, then drawing works without any lag but popping bubbles doesn't work.

```
    let gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognized(_:)))

            gestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
            gestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1


            view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Drawing view class

```
    import UIKit

    class DrawingView: UIView {

        var drawColor = UIColor.black
        var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5

        private var lastPoint: CGPoint!
        private var bezierPath: UIBezierPath!
        private var pointCounter: Int = 0
        private let pointLimit: Int = 128
        private var preRenderImage: UIImage!

        // MARK: - Initialization

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            initBezierPath()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)

            initBezierPath()
        }

        func initBezierPath() {
            bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
            bezierPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
            bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.round
        }

        // MARK: - Touch handling

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
            lastPoint = touch!.location(in: self)
            pointCounter = 0
        }

        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
            let newPoint = touch!.location(in: self)

            bezierPath.move(to: lastPoint)
            bezierPath.addLine(to: newPoint)
            lastPoint = newPoint

            pointCounter += 1

            if pointCounter == pointLimit {
                pointCounter = 0
                renderToImage()
                setNeedsDisplay()
                bezierPath.removeAllPoints()
            }
            else {
                setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }

        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            pointCounter = 0
            renderToImage()
            setNeedsDisplay()
            bezierPath.removeAllPoints()
        }

        override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
            touchesEnded(touches!, with: event)
        }

        // MARK: - Pre render

        func renderToImage() {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
            if preRenderImage != nil {
                preRenderImage.draw(in: self.bounds)
            }

            bezierPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
            drawColor.setFill()
            drawColor.setStroke()
            bezierPath.stroke()

            preRenderImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        // MARK: - Render

        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            super.draw(rect)

            if preRenderImage != nil {
                preRenderImage.draw(in: self.bounds)
            }

            bezierPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
            drawColor.setFill()
            drawColor.setStroke()
            bezierPath.stroke()
        }

        // MARK: - Clearing

        func clear() {
            preRenderImage = nil
            bezierPath.removeAllPoints()
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }

        // MARK: - Other

        func hasLines() -> Bool {
            return preRenderImage != nil || !bezierPath.isEmpty
        }

    }
```